# Зачем нужен знак ">" в CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, зачем нужен "`>`" в CSS?

В чем отличие?

```
.block > p > span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.block > p span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.block p > span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.block p span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: ``>`` означает "прямой потомок": только дочерний элемент, а не "внучатый". https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=1256

Answer (score 1):

Дело в подчинении.

Фишка в том, что `>` указывает на те элементы, которые находятся именно в этом классе.

Думаю, по примерам будет довольно просто понять:

```css
.menu > li {
  background: blue; // Красим элементы ТОЛЬКО в классе .menu, li .submenu не трогаем
}

.submenu > li {
  background: red; // Красим элементы ТОЛЬКО в классе .submenu, li .menu не трогаем
}

.menu li {
  background: pink; // Красим ВСЕ li, которые в .menu и в .submenu
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>menu item 1</li>
  <li>menu item 2</li>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li>submenu item 1</li>
    <li>submenu item 2</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```